# CompletableFuture List wait for all future issue

Tags: java-8, completable-future

I have the below list of CompletableFuture pipeline

```
for (Integer unit : getIds()) {
        futureList.add(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(unit)
            .thenApply(id -> CompletableFuture
                .completedFuture(service.get1(id))
                .thenCombineAsync(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(b), (a, df1) -> 
                    CompletableFuture.completedFuture(service.validate(Optional.ofNullable(a),c, 
                            b, dealerCode))
                    .thenApplyAsync(status -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture(b))
                    .thenCombineAsync(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(a), (b1, a1) -> 
                        service.mapToTrans(Optional.ofNullable(a), b, c))
                    .handle((response, exception) -> {
                        if(exception == null) {
                            return response;
                        }
                        else {
                            handler.handleException(exception, results);
                            return null;
                        }
                    })
                    .thenApplyAsync(t -> service.submitRequest(Optional.ofNullable(a), c))
                    .thenApplyAsync((t) -> service.saveTransaction(Optional.ofNullable(t)))
                    .thenAccept(result1 -> results.add(result1))
                )
                .handle((response, exception) -> handleStage(response, exception, results))
            )
            .handle((response, exception) -> handleStage(response, exception, results))
            );
    }
```

The results array holds the result of all the futures. In the main method this is how I am waiting for all the futures to get completed

```
CompletableFuture<Void> allFutures = CompletableFuture
            .allOf(futureList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futureList.size()]));
CompletableFuture<List<Object>> allFutureExec = allFutures.thenApply(v -> {
            return futureList.stream().map(pg-> pg.join()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        });
allFutureExec.get();
```

The "results" list is supposed to contain the result of all future chain But I can see that main thread is not waiting for all the stages to get executed. The result list has the result of only few futures, though I can see from the logs that all the futures are getting executed. Please let me know if this is the correct way to wait for all the futures to get completed.

UPDATE-1

```
for (Integer unit : getIds()) {
        futureList.add(CompletableFuture
                .completedFuture(service.get1(unit))
                .thenCombine(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(td), (vd, dealerInfo1) -> 
                    CompletableFuture.completedFuture(service.validate(Optional.ofNullable(vd),sd, 
                        td))
                    .thenApply(status -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture(service.mapToTrans
                            (Optional.ofNullable(vd), td,trade, userCredential))
                    .thenApplyAsync(transaction -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture(service.submit(Optional.ofNullable(vd),transaction))
                    .thenApply((transaction1) -> service.saveTransaction(Optional.ofNullable(transaction1)))
                    .thenApply(result1 -> results.add(result1)))))
        );      

    }
```

Comment: This is not a pipeline. It’s a sequence of calls, every one ignoring the results of the previous call. It starts with `CompletableFuture.completedFuture(unit) .thenApply(id -> CompletableFuture .completedFuture(service.get1(id))` which is a convoluted way to get the equivalent of `CompletableFuture .completedFuture(service.get1(unit))`—no asynchronous operation involved so far.

Comment: It continues with `.thenCombineAsync(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(b), (a, df1) -> …`, a superfluous use of “combine”, it would be no different if you used `.thenApplyAsync( a -> …` instead, you’re already using `b` directly instead of the `df1` parameter which would hold the contents of `b` in the combine function. This pattern of useless use of “combine” appears twice. Then, there’s `.thenApplyAsync(status -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture(b))` wrapping `b` in a future without any reason, but the parameter `b1` in the next step, which references that future, is ignored anyway.

Comment: But besides containing 99% obsolete code, the actual problem likely is `.thenAccept(result1 -> results.add(result1))` chained to an asynchronous operation; it requires `result` to be a thread safe collection and in case of a `List`, you have to understand that the element order still isn’t guaranteed.

Comment: Thank you. That was a valuable feedback. I have overlooked some items. I have refactored the code as per your suggestion (UPDATE-1).  Still I have to use thenCombine because parameter "vd" is passed to subsequent meethod calls. Please let me know if there is a better way to handle this. Regarding your third comment, I am using Collections.synchronizedList, and order does not matter for me. I will test the code and check if list is getting data as expected

Comment: But when you use `.thenCombine(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(td), (vd, dealerInfo1) -> …`, the parameter `dealerInfo1` will be the same as `td`, that’s what you *combine*, but you’re not using `dealerInfo1` anywhere. So you can just use `.thenApply(vd -> …` instead. Note that `vd` still is available in the function then.

Comment: In short, every occurrence of `CompletableFuture.completedFuture` in that code is either, obsolete or highly suspicious. I guess, your problem stems from one of these wrappings, e.g. a service method returning a future that you wrap in another, *completed* future, so you’re not waiting for the completion.

Comment: The service method does not return a future, but actual domain objects.